# Falsely getting "The request was aborted because it exceeded the maximum execution time"

Tags: php

I say "falsely" because:

- this script runs comparatively faster than other similar scripts in the same application and it uses an extremely similar structure (it takes about 5 seconds with breakpoints if click continue when debugging)
- none of my other scripts time-out
- almost all of my scripts contain something like this:

  ```
  //give script enough time to run    
  $rowcount = count($rows);
  set_time_limit(3 * $rowcount);
  ```
- the bit that is timing-out is an `execute()` in a PDO wrapper class that I use on every page of my application

So my question is: what can cause this error if the maximum execution time is not being exceeded?

Comment: hmmm, what it $rows = 0 ?

Comment: If set to zero, no time limit is imposed. @Jorge Campos

Comment: Post more code...

Comment: You're probably setting `set_time_limit` after the bit that is causing the problem.

Comment: `set_time_limit(3 * $rowcount);` why?

Comment: Why do I do that based on `$rowcount`? I did it because all the scripts are heavily involved with a database with unknown amounts of data. I don't want them to run forever, but I do want each iteration to add to the time the script is "allowed" to run for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in my own mess.

I said "it takes about 5 seconds..." but I've only given 3 seconds per record.

With 1 record, the script times out because it only has 3 seconds...